# React работа с атрибутами простого тега, или как картинку из 1 тега переместить в другой

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, create-react-app, react-router-dom

Картинка ниже в принципе всё подробно описывает, главное, использовать React, как такое сделать на JS или JQuery я и так знаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду сильно благодарен за ответ.

Так же это обязательно должно быть БЕЗ изменения адресной строки

Comment: Знаю как сделать на JS, но не знаю как на React... это как?

Comment: Просто передаешь `state` из одного компонента к другому.

Comment: Изучайте реакт-хуки из официальной документации: https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, такое поведение можно сделать с помощью css см пример:
https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=2&id=1226
Во-вторых, решение может сильно зависеть от html-скелета, но в целом, в событии `onClick` мы получим id/src/data-tag картинки и установим в какую-то `state`-переменную; в результате изменения `state` компонент перерендерится и возьмет в большой контейнер новое значение

Comment: лучше было бы для ТС написать маленький пример